# Сайт не отправил данных

Tags: php, form

Есть страница с формой, при нажатии на submit пересылает на странице handler.php, но вместо того что бы что-то сделать пишет:

```
Страница недоступна
Сайт site.com не отправил данных.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Не работает даже на простом примере

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

handler.php

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: выложите код формы и обработчика. Ванг тут нет.

Comment: Код обработчик php покажите, а ещё лучше логи серверные приложить.

Comment: Ну раз она не доступна, то что вы от нее хотите? Значит не верно указываете путь к обработчику.

Comment: @Durrasell, показал

Comment: @Suvitruf выложил

Comment: путь не с рута. обработчик в этой же папке?

Comment: Пробовали другие браузеры?  Также возможно есть ошибка в конфигурации сайта

Comment: Покажите структуру папок проекта.

Comment: @Durrasell да в той же папке

Comment: ну нужно видеть структуру папок.

Comment: еще может быть фронтконтоллер и htaccess которые не дают пробиться по урлу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче кому было интересно в чем проблема... На сервере стоял PHP 7.0, а я использовал eval(), но на PHP 7 он не работает! Причем  когда строчка была закомментированная код не работал)

P.S.  Спасибо, всем кто пытался помочь)